# Assign Keycloak Realm Roles to User based on the type of Registration URL

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

Consider I have two registration pages:

```
1) Student : /register-student

2) Tutor   : /register-tutor

I have another URL for login : /login
```

Now for each of them I have their own callback URL's.

```
/callback-student
/callback-tutor
/callback
```

On registration once the user is authenticated, based on the Callback we assign the respective roles. And then redirect the user to the home page.

Note: Once registration is done we do not let the user be authenticated. Rather we redirect the user to login page and expect the user to login.

Once the user logs in, he is authenticated and at the same time I expect to have the user mapped to the right role as we have Role based policies on our resources.

This is my approach of doing the registration, I want to know if this is the right way to do it using Keycloak.

If there is a better way, it would be helpful if you can provide links wherein I can refer to and implement the same.

Comment: Hi! Have you solved this problem, please. I am blocked by the same. Thank you!

Comment: @EliaquimTchitalacumbi I went ahead with the approach of making the user login again once the registration is done.

Comment: @AbhishekShenoy, how?